# The image of a polynomial curve $p:F\to F^2$ lies in the zero set of another polynomial $q:F^2\to F$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, abstract-algebra

> Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is an infinite field. Define $p:\mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{F}^2$
>   as $p(t)=(p_1(t),p_2(t))$ where $p_1,p_2:\mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{F}$ are
>   polynomials.
>   Show that the image of $p$ lies in the zero set of some polynomial
>   $q:\mathbb{F}^2\to\mathbb{F}$.
>
> (Bonus) Give a lower bound to the degree of $q$.

Any polynomial $q:\mathbb{F}^2\to\mathbb{F}$ of degree $D$ looks like
$$q(x,y)=\sum_{0\leq i+j\leq D}c_{ij}x^iy^j\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
where $c_{ij}\in\mathbb{F}$. Now finding $q$ is solving the equation $$q(p(t))=q(p_1(t),p_2(t))=0.(2)$$ Plugging (1) in (2) we will have the equation
$$\sum_{0\leq i+j\leq D}c_{ij}p_1(t)^ip_2(t)^j=0,\;\;\text{ for all }t\in\mathbb{F}.$$

Since this is true for all $t\in\mathbb{F}$ and the field is infinite, we can choose $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{N=\frac{(D+1)(D+2)}{2}}$ values for $t$ from $\mathbb{F}$ so that we get a system
\begin{cases}
\sum_{0\leq i+j\leq D}c_{ij}p_1(t_1)^ip_2(t_1)^j=0\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{0\leq i+j\leq D}c_{ij}p_1(t_N)^ip_2(t_N)^j=0
\end{cases}

So now we want to show that there exists those $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_N$ that make this system not invertible. How to do that?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem, especially since there's a "bonus" part, so it really doesn't belong on this site. But here's a one-word hint to get you started: "Resultant"

Comment: Put $P(t) := x - p_1(t)$ and $Q(t)=y-p_2(t)$ and compute Sylvester's resultant w.r.t. to $t$, see http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/topics_nth/Resultants.pdf

Comment: Well actually I added the bonus and it is a homework problem. I need hints or comments on my approach. I'm not sure it will lead anywhere.

Comment: @Holonomia, $p_1$ and $p_2$'s degrees are arbitrary.  Computing the determinant is not easy. And plus, is the determinant going to be the polynomial that I need?

Comment: The lower bound is simply $1$, obtained when $p_1 = p_2$. More generally, you have to check for a common decomposition factor. If $p_1 = \tilde{p}_1(p)$ and $p_2 = \tilde{p}_2(p)$ then you can replace $p_1,p_2$ by $\tilde{p}_1,\tilde{p}_2$. If there is no non-trivial decomposition factor, then the degrees of $p_1,p_2$ are simply the degrees of $q$ with respect to the two variables (since those are the degrees you get from the resultant).

Comment: Adel: the resultant will be a power of the polynomial $q$. Namely, it will be $q^n$ where $n$ is the degree of the largest common decomposition factor $p$. If $n=1$ then the resultant is certainly the fastest way to find $q$. If $n>1$, this decomposition can also be found quickly.

Comment: @Mark whats the largest common decomposition of $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working too hard. To say that $p_1$ and $p_2$ satisfy a polynomial relationship is equivalent to saying that the polynomials $\{ p_1^i p_2^j \}$ must be linearly dependent. We can prove this using a degree argument: if $\deg p_k = d_k$, then $p_1^i p_2^j$ has degree $d_1 i + d_2 j$. The number of these polynomials of degree less than or equal to $D$ is then the number of nonnegative integer solutions to the inequality

$$d_1 i + d_2 j \le D.$$

It's not hard to see that this number grows like the area of a triangle with side lengths $\frac{D}{d_1}, \frac{D}{d_2}$, so grows something like $\frac{D^2}{2 d_1 d_2}$, which in particular is quadratic in $D$. On the other hand, the dimension of the space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $D$ is $D+1$, which is linear in $D$. So as soon as $D$ is large enough there must be a linear dependence, and "large enough" is around $2 d_1 d_2$.